# django: why it shows only one TabularInline object instance?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've two classes:

```
class Post(models.Model):
```

and

```
class Image(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    post = models.ForeignKey("Post", unique=True, related_name='posts')
```

the problem is that in admin site I see only ONE Tabular/StackedInline object Image for a Post.

Here is my admin.py

```
class ImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image
    fk_name = 'post'
    extra = 5

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ImageInline,
    ]
    list_display = ('name', )
    search_fields = ['name',]
    ...

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

...where I'm worng ? According to extra parameter in TabularInline I should have 3 images to add to Post...but it only shows up 1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only allowing one image per post, because you're specifying `unique=True` on the ForeignKey.